# Exercise 5 of Tao's Blog about Lie groups, Lie algebras, and the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I just began studying the Lie group, and I really don't know how to solve the first part of Exercise 5:

> Let $G$ be a (global) Lie group.
>
> 1. Show that for every element $x$ of $T_1G$ there is a unique left-invariant vector fiel $X \in \Gamma(TG)$ such that $X(1) = x$.
> 2. Show that the commutator $[X,Y]$ of two left-invariant vector fields is again a left-invariant vector field.

Comment: Use the left translation map, acting on vectors, to push your vector to any point on the group. By construction the resulting vector field will be left invariant

Comment: @ziggurism  you mean $X(x)=xX(1)$ ?

Comment: no, vector fields live at points of the group, but $x$ is a tangent vector, so $X(x)$ doesn't make sense. Should be$ X(g) = g__* x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any element $g\in G$ we have a left multiplication map $L_g\colon G\to G$.  Given $x\in T_1G$, we can define $X\in \Gamma(TG)$ by
\begin{equation}
X(g) = dL_g(x).
\end{equation}
Notice that $X(1)=dL_1(x)=x$, since $L_1$ is the identity map on $G$.  Also, $X$ is left-invariant by construction.  Now suppose $Y\in\Gamma(TG)$ is left invariant and $Y(1)=x$.  Then for any $g\in G$,
\begin{equation}
Y(g)=dL_g(Y(1))=dL_g(x)=X(g),
\end{equation}
so $Y=X$, meaning that $X$ is the unique left-invariant vector field with $X(1)=x$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to understand and define the left action $g\in G$ on vector field $X$ ? $(gX)(y)=gX(g^{-1}y)$. I don't know why to define it so .

Comment: Hmm...I don't immediately recognize that definition.  In particular, the right side seems strange since we're acting on the vector $X(g^{-1}y)$ by the group element $g$.

Comment: Yes, I also feel it is strange, I think it should be $g_*X(g^{-1}y)$

Comment: Why $X$ is left-invariant by construction ?

Comment: We say that $X$ is left-invariant if for every $g,h\in G$, $X(gh)=dL_g(X(h))$.  According to our definition, $X(gh)=dL_{gh}(x)=d(L_g\circ L_h)(x)=dL_g(dL_h(x))=dL_g(X(h))$, using the chain rule.